# How to deploy a Javascript application on gitHub?

Tags: github

I have a application built using HTML5,CSS3,Bootstrap,Javascript and Jquery.I want to deploy the application on github .

Any suggestions on how to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to read some guides firstly. Like this one:

> https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/

You have to install git on your local PC, then create your own repository on git and clone it to your computer. After that, you will be able to store your JS project in that repository and simply commit, push and pull all tha changes you did.

Have fun!